# Reading the data in the file in a certain way

Tags: c++

i have some txt file . content  of this file like that

- ID: 01
- REQ: 22 12 34
- RES: 62 12 34 69 51 6D 69 6E 65
  i want just 2. row but without REQ: part(22 12 34)

  ```
    ifstream file("simulation.txt");
    int counter=1;
    if (file.is_open())
   {
    string line;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
    //  cout << line << endl;
        if(counter==2){
        cout << line << endl;
        }
        counter++;
    }
  ```

  }
  this is my code i can finde 2. row but how can i delet REQ: part

Comment: You'll need equal quantity of numbers in row 2 and 3.

Comment: What part of the reading are you having issues with?

Comment: I recommend using a `std::map<int,int>` to associate numbers, such as `map[22] == 62`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i can read line by line but i cant read by number

Comment: Post your current code and what issues you have with it. In general, read a basic tutorial on reading files, like https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/. Note that you can iterate over a line and check for space, for purposes of delimiting.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  map is it a function ? Is it a function that comes with iostream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have stated that you can get the line you want. So from here, we can simplify the problem to just this:

```
std::string line = "REQ: 22 12 34";
std::string only_the_bit_i_want = ???;
```

There are lots of ways, we can approach this. Here is one.

Do you know that the line will always have `"REQ: "` at the front? If so that is exactly 5 characters, so lets just get the string after 5 characters:

```
std::string only_the_bit_i_want = line.substr(5);
```

see [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).